# Suggestion Needed on using GSM to sip gateway with freeswitch in C#

Tags: c#, gsm

I am considering using 2N® VoiceBlue Lite with Freeswitch to serve as a GSM to sip gateway that will route gsm calls to fs server for an IVR system to be built with C# anybody who has tested this or anybody with any suggestions or opinion?

Answer (score 1):

What does your IVR system need to achieve? If it's routing call then you can do this fairly easily with the freeswitch dialplans.

Anything more complicated might require a programming language. I've used LUA in FS and this works very well. LUA is integrated well and there's a lot of help on the web for how to program FS using LUA.

2N VoiceBlueLite looks like a standard GSM gateway and calls can be sent from the 2N in SIP to FS. DTMF is handled by 2N with RFC2833 so this won't cause a problem on freeswitch.

You *might* find that you are getting double digits on Freeswitch - this sometimes happens with SIP so best practice is to explicitly state that you're using RFC2833 at the beginning of your inbound dialplan.